# Django: Where to put helper functions?

Tags: python, django

I have a couple of functions that I wrote that I need to use in my django app. Where would I put the file with them and how would I make them callable within my views?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I usually put such app specific helper function in file utils.py and use someting like this

```
from myapp.utils import my_cool_func

def view_coolness(request):
    data = my_cool_func(request)
    return render_to_response("xxx.html")
```

but it depends what you helper does, may be they modify request , the could be part of middleware, so you need to tell what exactly those helper functions do

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mention the app in the code. Just doing `from utils import my_cool_func` should work without having to re-state the name of the app which you're already in.

Comment: @Peter Bengtsson, may be but how do you import utils in a module in a package e.g. I have views folder with several view modules, and then middleware folders etc

Comment: @PeterBengtsson, why is a bad idea? EDIT: oops, this is 2009 (I'm still curious though )

Comment: Wow 2009 was very different. Basically, if something can be said in less words, say it in less words. Also not being tied to the name is a good thing if you decide to rename it.

Comment: means you can't easily move the module for example

Comment: I would use `from .utils import func`

Comment: Is it possible to have a global function used in several apps?

Answer (score 20):

If they are related to a specific app, I usually just put them in the related app folder and name the file, 'functions.py'.

If they're not specific to an app, I make a `commons` app for components (tests, models, functions, etc) that are shared across apps.

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 19):

create a reusable app that include your generic functions so you can share between projects.

use for example a git repo to store this app and manage deployments and evolution (submodule)

use a public git repo so you can share with the community :)

Answer (score 4):

I am using new python file `service.py` in app folder. The file contains mostly helper queries for specific app. Also I used to create a folder inside Django application that contains global helper functions and constants.